# Node.js require NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm very new to Node.js and I've been stuck on something very basic for a while now. Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to do some tests with a headless browser (in this case: Puppeteer).

- I've installed Node and NPM on my Windows machine
- I've ininiated NPM in my project folder
- I've installed puppeteer and I see the folder in my node_modules folder
- Then I try to run the basic example script.

When I run the command in cmd:

```
node puppeteerbot.js
```

I just get a blinking cursor, that's it. I've tried other headless browsers, but they did the same thing. So it's probably something in my process that I'm doing wrong. When I remove the folder from my node_modules and run the command, I get the logical 'can't find module' error. What does a blinking cursor mean? Is it running endlessly?

The code of puppeteerbot.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.duckduckgo.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I hope my question makes sense, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you share with us the content of `puppetterbot.js`?

Comment: I would suggest running Node with the inspector so you can see what the code is doing. Run the command `node --inspect-brk puppetterbot.js` and open the Chrome Node inspector by typing `about:inspect` in Google Chrome. You can now step though your code line by line to see what is happening.

Comment: @hardkoded: I've added the code, but found a fix for my problem just now.

Comment: @KrisSinclair, thank you for your suggestion! I managed to get the debugging working, but couldn't find any strange behaviour. The problem was not in my code, but that I was running my project on a NAS and not on my local drive. When I moved the project folder to a local drive, all problems were solved!